# onYouTubeIframeAPIReady inside jQuery(document).ready

Tags: javascript, api, iframe, youtube

What I want to do is:

1. Wait for the document to render;
2. When YouTube iframe api is ready, initialize my custom function and pass the `YT` object to it so I can build the player from inside.

This is what I have done so far. It works but I have feeling something is very wrong. I am not sure it should be done this way.

```
jQuery.getScript("http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"); // load YT api

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    new my_custom_function().init(YT); // init my function and pass YT object
  };
});
```

I'd appreciate it if someone can clarify what's the best way to do this. I do really need to build the players from inside `my_custom_function()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function has to be in a global scope, I suppose we can't bind it in jQuery's *document ready* callback. One of the workarounds I see is to use [jQuery deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). At first we create a deffered object and resolve it in `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` callback

```
 var YTdeferred = $.Deferred();
 window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
   YTdeferred.resolve(window.YT);
 };
```

and then waiting for deferred object to be resolved after *document ready*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  YTdeferred.done(function(YT) {
    // use YT here
  });
});
```

[See the full example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBZu9/1/)